# req.session is undefined nodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

im trying to set up a session in NodeJS and use it in my /auth route after that but i'm getting undefined troubles with the session.

In the app.js :

```
const express = require('express'),
  path = require('path'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  cors = require('cors'),
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  config = require('./config/DB');

const app = express();
  const session = require('express-session')
  const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

mongoose.connect(config.DB, { useNewUrlParser: true }).then(
  () => { console.log('Database is connected') },
  err => { console.log('Can not connect to the database' + err) },
  options
);
const db = mongoose.connection


const adUnitRoutes = require('./routes/adunit.route');
const userProfileRoutes = require('./routes/userprofile.route');


app.use('/adunits', adUnitRoutes);
app.use('/userprofile', userProfileRoutes);

app.use(session({
  secret: 'my-secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: db })
}));
```

In the route :

```
userProfileRoutes.route('/authentification').post((req, res) => {

  console.log('req session : ' + req.session.userId);
//here I got cant read property of userId because session is undefined

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you are setting your routes before adding the middleware. Your handlers are essentially middleware so if they are added before `session`, your session has not been processed and added to the request yet.

Adding the routes after setting your middleware will make it work as expected.

See this minimized example:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const session = require('express-session');

app.get('/broken', (req, res) => {
  console.log('req session : ' + req.session.userId);
  res.write(String(req.session.userId));
  req.session.userId = 1;
  res.end();
});

app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'my-secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
  })
);

app.get('/ok', (req, res) => {
  console.log('req session : ' + req.session.userId);
  res.write(String(req.session.userId));
  req.session.userId = 1;
  res.end();
});

app.listen(8089);
```

Comment: Seems logic but I missed it. I'll remember it, thanks. But after refactoring and placing the session before the routes, I'm still getting an undefined statement for req.session.userId after my ('/auth').post route. Any other suggestions?

Comment: do you mean `req.session.userId` is `undefined` or `req.session` is `undefined`? The former would make sense until you set the value in the session (`req.session.userId = 1;`), the latter would mean the error is in the difference between your code and my minimal example.

Comment: Yeah my bad, I think I missed one thing. Do we have to manually assign a value to the req.session.userId? I thought the assignment of a default value was automatic. Thanks for the help

Comment: Yes, you control the value of everything in your `req.session` (your `userId` is application logic specific to your service). Glad to hear it helped!

Comment: Im just getting confused about smthing and maybe you could help me (once again :P). On the page after auth, my userId is well defined as I wanted like Session { cookie: ... } , {userId : idFromDB}. But after navigation, this userId disapears and the Session is now like Session {cookie : ...} without the variable userID. Isnt the session supposed to keep in memory cache the variable through all pages, so I can use it anywhere on the app? Thanks in advance

Comment: As far as I know the session should persist between calls, if that's not working I would need more context to be able to know what's going on. Feel free to add another question with a [mcve] of the new error and let me know :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53224056/req-session-userid-disapears-on-other-nodejs-routes Here is the topic a little more detailled, if you could help me I'd be grateful :)