# Why setting the cookie.secure to True in express session allows session id and data to persist?

Tags: node.js, express, session, cookies

I am currently learning the MERN stack and working on a small project that requires me to have some session data that can persist between routes.

It works as intended, but whenever I go to an incorrect route or go back to the landing page and log the session id `console.log(req.session.id)` It is different every time.

So I did some digging, and from some previous stackoverflow posts, [session not persisting when using secure cookie in NodeJS with express-session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53224056/session-not-persisting-when-using-secure-cookie-in-nodejs-with-express-session), Setting the `cookie: { secure: false }` while testing on http seems to solve my problem. The session id and by extension the session data persists.

I want to know why setting `cookie: { secure: false }` in the express session options allows the session id and data to persist, and not having it does not.

Here is my session options

```js
server.use(session({
        secret: 'sxexsxsxixoxn',
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        cookie: { secure: false }
    }))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `cookie: {secure: true}`, the cookie will only be set over an https connection, and not over an http connection. See also [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#secure).

So if you only have an http server, you must set `cookie: {secure: false}`, otherwise no cookies will be set and session handling will not work.