# Cookie not save in browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, mern

[enter image description here][1]Im developed web app react frontend and node backend.when user login I try to save cookie in browser .in postman testing cookie show but not save in browser.(I used also jwt authentication)In browser this error show,* Indicate whether a cookie is intended to be set in a cross-site context by specifying its SameSite attribute* .and I update with sameSite none and secure true but still not save cookie in browser.How to slove this

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting your web app on localhost you should set `secure:false` or else cookies are not going to work. You should set `secure:true` only when you deploy your web app. The reason is setting this option to true says that the cookies should be send over https **(secure)** connection but when you are on localhost you are on http **(not secure)** connection so coookies will not be sent. For more info check a previous question:

[Why setting the cookie.secure to True in express session allows session id and data to persist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71184167/why-setting-the-cookie-secure-to-true-in-express-session-allows-session-id-and-d)

Comment: I do but not save cookie below is the error message .It says my accessToken Affected
Resolve this issue by updating the attributes of the cookie:
Specify SameSite=None and Secure if the cookie is intended to be set in cross-site contexts. Note that only cookies sent over HTTPS may use the Secure attribute.
Specify SameSite=Strict or SameSite=Lax if the cookie should not be set by cross-site requests.
1 cookie
Name Domain & Path
accessToken localhost/

Comment: Please edit your question and copy paste your code and the error.

Answer (score 0):

1 - in forntend fetch request must include this :

```
credentials: 'include',
```

2 - in backend cookies attribute must include those :

```
{ httpOnly: true,secure:true, sameSite:'None'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Postman fixed the issue, it's working in `Version 10.21.9`. Now you don't need to set `secure:false` for dev and `secure:true` explicitly. You can just use `secure:true` with your any environment.